# Since I can't use strings as the argument for a switch statement what should I use?

Tags: c++, string, switch-statement

Since a switch statement doesn't take in a string what other than a switch statement is there that I should use. Is there anything that I could use which won't require me to write a ton of if statements? Or is there a way to make switch statements take in a string? I need another way other than a switch statement so I can check for multiple ( > 20) different cases.

```
vector<string> tokens;
string present;
while(....){
string right_value = right->evaluate();  <-- finds out what the string to the right of present is 
string left_value = left->evaluate();   <-- finds out what the string to the left of present is. 
switch(present){
 case "write" : return right_value;
.
.
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Use a map of string to function . And why do you think that using a switch is superior to using if/else? The latter is typically shorter, clearer and more flexible. I've never understood this idea that switches are some magic solution to all programming problems.

Comment: Depends on your use-case, in particular, the logic inside the switch cases. As you don't provide the code with this logic, the question is likely to be close as "too broad". But here is a hint: create a dictionary with wich you can translate the condition into resulting data or action. It can be an array, `std::map` or something else.

Comment: You can use `if`.

Comment: @NickA the example's mentioned (using enums, etc) would take a lot of time to do. I need something simple and easily. That's why I want something similar to the switch statement

Comment: @Galik I have specified that I need it for checking multiple cases so if statements wont be a good idea

Comment: It's hard to beat a set of `if` statements. You can't avoid writing one statement per `case` whatever you do.

Comment: @Low_level_dir I still don't understand why `switch` would be any better than `if`, you're just replacing `if`/`else if` with `case`/`break`

Comment: @NickA it is just very time consuming and I have to then I would have so many if statements the code would be just unbearable

Comment: How is a stack of `if` statements so different from a stack of `case` statements?

Comment: which would look nice? 
a bunch of :
if (present == "write"){
cout << right_value << endl;
}

or

case "write" : return right value;
break:

Comment: Well I am biased because I always thought `switch/case: break;` looked clunky. :)

Comment: Or, `if(present == "write") return right_value;`

Comment: @Galik oh ya forgot that would work too